# In drop down, all values are showing from column. need only one time value

Tags: c#

`DropDownList` needs only one value for one time.

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.;initial catalog=Rupesh;integrated security=true");
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da;
string query;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        con.Open();

        query = "select * from vendor";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[4].ToString());

        }

        con.Close();

        vendordetails();
    }
}

private void vendordetails()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        query = "select * from vendor";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        query = "select * from vendor where vendor_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide more details whats showing up and what kind of result is expected. Its a bit unclear what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
"select * from vendor"
```

use something like

```
"select [columnname] from vendor"
```

Replace [columnname] with the name of the column you want to display.

The * gets you all values from all columns from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    query = "select * from vendor";
}
```

you need

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    query = "select distinct vendor_name from vendor";
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what he's after but one would hope the rows in the Vendor table would be unique anyway :)

Comment: Yeah I expect it to be so but you know how the world is :)

Comment: A case may be he is trying to fill the grid based on the name. So there may be vendors with the same name so he might be trying to pull all vendors with same know. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am assuming that when you select a Vendor from the Drop down, you want to see the vendor details in the grid.

You seem to be not far off......

Adjust your proc vendordetails() to be.............

```
private void vendordetails(string vendorName = "")
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        query =  String.Format( "select * from vendor where vendor_name = \'{0}\'", vendorName);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged simply have....

```
vendordetails(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
```